# How do I install Magento Bitcoin currency extension?

Tags: magento, plugins, installation, bitcoin

How do I install [the Magento Bitcoin currency extension](https://github.com/ticean/magento-bitcoin) on a Linux box with standard LAMP stack?

I have already searched, read the documentation, and put the files in the root Magento directory (just as the instructions say to do: https://github.com/ticean/magento-bitcoin/wiki/Installation).

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy files from /lib/ into your /lib/.

Then everything in /app/ into your /app/.

Make sure to upload /design/ into the correct template you are using.

Code is going into /community/, NOT core or local.

Finally, ScaleWorks_Bitcoin.xml goes into /app/etc/modules.

Verify that Magento can see the module in Admin -> Config -> Advanced. Does the module show up on that list?